# Finding the expected values of the area of a circle

Tags: probability, expected-value, uniform-distribution

Suppose a circle is drawn with random radius R, that is uniformly distributed between 0 and a constant c. How to find the expected value of  the area Y = pi R² of such a circle?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E[Y] = E[\pi R^2] = \pi E[R^2] = \pi \cdot \int_{0}^{c}t^2f_R{t}
=  \pi \cdot \int_{0}^{c}t^2\cdot \frac{1}{c}
= \pi \cdot \int_{0}^{c}t^2\cdot \frac{1}{c} 
= \pi \frac{c^2}{3}
$$

Used: Linearity of expected value, Linearity of integrals,Smooth transformation of continous Random variable